# Rerunning Selenium tests make Maven build fail

Tags: selenium, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

We have a set of UI tests run nightly, and sometimes some of the tests fail due to network glitches. To avoid false-negative test results, I used `IRtetryAnalyzer` which re-runs failed tests upto 3 times.

It works perfectly when I run tests from Eclispe right-clicking on the suite.xml -  if a test fails at first but passes when retried, the first result is not counted as failure.

But when running same tests as part of `Maven` build, the build fails if any of the tests fail, even if successfully pass at retry.

For example, running a suite of 5 tests where one fails at first but passes on second attempt gives me this output when run as `TestNG` suite:

> Total tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Skips: 0

But with Maven, the result is different:

> Tests run: 6, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Is there a way to make `Maven` not count rerun tests as failure?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it. I use this code:

**ListenerApadter**:

```
public class MyTestListenerAdapter extends TestListenerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        if (result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer() != null) {
            MyRetryAnalyzer retryAnalyzer = (MyRetryAnalyzer)result.getMethod().getRetryAnalyzer();

            if(retryAnalyzer.isRetryAvailable()) {
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.SKIP);
            } else {
                result.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
            }
            Reporter.setCurrentTestResult(result);
        }
    }

   @Overrride
   public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
     Iterator<ITestResult> failedTestCases =context.getFailedTests().getAllResults().iterator();
    while (failedTestCases.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("failedTestCases");
        ITestResult failedTestCase = failedTestCases.next();
        ITestNGMethod method = failedTestCase.getMethod();
        if (context.getFailedTests().getResults(method).size() > 1) {
            System.out.println("failed test case remove as dup:" + failedTestCase.getTestClass().toString());
            failedTestCases.remove();
        } else {

            if (context.getPassedTests().getResults(method).size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("failed test case remove as pass retry:" + failedTestCase.getTestClass().toString());
                failedTestCases.remove();
            }
        }
    }
   }
}
```

**RetryAnalizer**:

```
public class MyRetryAnalyzer implements IRetryAnalyzer {
    private static int MAX_RETRY_COUNT = 3;

    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(MAX_RETRY_COUNT);

    public boolean isRetryAvailable() {
        return (count.intValue() > 0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
        boolean retry = false;
        if (isRetryAvailable()) {
            System.out.println("Going to retry test case: " + result.getMethod() + ", " + (MAX_RETRY_COUNT - count.intValue() + 1) + " out of " + MAX_RETRY_COUNT);
            retry = true;
            count.decrementAndGet();
        }
        return retry;
    }
}
```

**POM.xml -> Surefire Configuration:**

This is where you should configure "overwrite" surefire listener wich has their own counters.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.18.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles><suiteXmlFile>${basedir}/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile></suiteXmlFiles>
 <properties> 
   <property>
    <name>listener</name>
    <value>Utils.MyTestListenerAdapter,Utils.MyRetryAnalizer</value>
   </property>
 </properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/testng-users/T3vn765W4mw/1Ag0lIJhRl8J)

I still can't remove failed and retried test results from all tests count, but at least my builds don't fail if tests pass on second or third execution.

Comment: I copy the file but the build is still failing (mvn test). Any idea?.